# Performance em consultas com filtro por string vs chave estrangeira

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, code-first

Estou trabalhando em um projeto `Asp.Net MVC 5` que utiliza `code first` e todas as entidades possuem uma propriedade chamada `UserId` do tipo `string`. Quando vou fazer consultas filtrando por um determinado usuário(`Asp.Net Identity`) faço assim:

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var products = await db.Products.Where(_ => _.UserId == currentUserId).ToListAsync();
```

Estou perdendo performance por não ter um relacionamento através de chave estrangeira e apenas guardar o `UserId` em uma propriedade `string`?

Comment: Um pequeno desabafo: umaa coisa que me desanimou no `Asp.Net Identity` foi a `UserId` ser uma `Guid` salva como `string`, mesmo não existindo um relacionamento entre Produtos e usuarios, você pode criar um indice para a coluna UserId em Products

Comment: Olá, @TobyMosque. Se eu add `[Index]` em cima da minha propriedade UserId a consulta será aprimorada ou preciso fazer mais alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1):

## Estou perdendo performance por não ter um relacionamento através de chave estrangeira e apenas guardar o `UserId` em uma propriedade `string`?

Está. Na verdade, você pode associar o seu `ApplicationUser` normalmente a qualquer outra entidade, tomando apenas alguns cuidados.

Para que a relação entre as entidades funcione, é preciso tomar o cuidado de envelopar o contexto com o `RoleManager` e o `UserManager` da seguinte forma:

```
UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
```

Em todo caso, se você sentir que está com muita perda de performance, sugiro reimplementar seu `ApplicationUser` usando como chave `Guid` ou `int`:

```
public class MeuUserComGuid : IdentityUser<Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim>
{
    public User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public User(string name) : this() { UserName = name; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que estou com as `Entidades` em um projeto separado e tem outros dois que fazem uso dele: o primeiro é um `Asp.Net MVC 5`, que utiliza autenticação padrão do `Asp.Net Identity` e outro `Web Api 2`, que utiliza autenticação via `Token` do `Asp.Net Identity`. Ou seja, não posso relacionar minhas `Entidades` com o ApplicationUser, pois o mesmo está dentro de projetos separados. Tentei juntar eles em um único projeto para criar esses relacionamentos, mas não consegui utilizar o Identity das duas formas necessárias. Sabe alguma alternativa?

Comment: Na verdade você pode, mas precisa separar apenas a camada *Model* das demais, numa *class library*. Isto implica instalar o ASP.NET Identity na *class library* também.

Comment: Instalei o `Identity` na camada `Model`, add a propriedade `public IdentityUser User { get; set; }` na entidade `Product` para criar o relacionamento e ao dar update-database da esse erro: _The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.IdentityUsers_Id". The conflict occurred in database "ChefAppDb", table "dbo.IdentityUsers", column 'Id'._ O que pode estar dando errado? Obs.: A classe `ApplicationUser` só é criada no arquivo `IdentityModels` ao criar um projeto `Asp.Net Mvc` ou `Web Api`, por isso usei a `IdentityUser`.

Comment: Isso acontece quando a *Migration* tenta criar a FK. Como a FK é não-nula, o erro ocorre. Faça um backup do banco, apague os dados das tabelas envolvidas e tente novamente.

Comment: não entendi onde eu add o código `UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context)); RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));` e o que seria o `context`?

Comment: O `DbContext`. A declaração fica no *Controller* em que você precisar selecionar e manipular usuários. É preciso encapsular desta forma, senão  o EF entende que tem dois contextos abertos.